# how to assign specific time pop up message in uipath with message box

Tags: uipath

I want to use message box as good morning message at 8:00 everyday but I couldnt assign the time interval. Can anyone help me to assign specicif time in uipath for message box

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

**While Loop**

Rather than a delay you could use a while loop to check the time.

So your sequence would be

```
While Date.Now.Hour <> 8
End While

Message Box "Good Morning"
```

[image: While Loop]

Obviously doing this you won't be able to do anything while the loop is running so isn't really going to work properly

**While Loop in Parallel**

The benefit this has over the above solution is that it can run while something else is running too

```
Parallel
  While True
    If Date.Now.Hour = 8
      Message Box "Good Morning"
    End If
  End While
End Parallel
```

[image: While Loop in Parallel]

Comment: I have tried your solution, it works properly but loop can not be removed. So, time is okay but how can we stop the loop while we set the time ?